# Leave Germany for few months after having registered

Tags: germany, immigration, residency

I am a an Italian university employee in Munich. I have rented a flat until the end of November and I did the "Anmeldung" in the offices of the burgeburo.

Now I need to leave Germany for 4 months due to a job travel.

Clearly I will not have an apartment in Germany for those months.

Should I do the "Abmeldung"? Am I still officially a resident in Germany?

Comment: "Clearly I will not have an apartment in Germany for those months." That's not at all obvious to me.  Depending on the details of your travel, I would expect an employer to pay for accommodation abroad for the duration of your secondment, and you to contain paying rent on the German apartment.

Comment: Ok, I think I could do like that. But suppose that I don't. Is it against any law? I mean, as a resident in Germany I always have to own or be renting a place in Germany?

Comment: As a European probably you are entitled to live in Germany or being resident there and go somewhere else, as long as you can provide for yourself.

Answer (score 2):

If I read your question correctly, then your plan is to end the lease and move out of your appartment.

In this situation, you would obviously have to de-register. What makes you think that you can continue to be registered as living in an apartment after ending your lease, moving out and returning the key?